# jQuery: Iterate through elements and move background-position of CSS Sprite

Tags: jquery

What I'm trying to do is create a list of swatches that, upon mouseover, show a preview of the color that is being hovered on. I'm using a CSS sprite to deliver both the swatches and the previews. I have it working, but I feel there is a far more efficient way to deliver the associated jQuery. I'm seeking help to find a more elegant solution.

**Below is my HTML:**

```
<div class="chip-preview"></div>
<div class="style-swatches">
<ul>
    <li class="c1"></li>
    <li class="c2"></li>
    <li class="c3"></li>
    <li class="c4"></li>
    <li class="c5"></li>
    <li class="c6"></li>
    <li class="c7"></li>
    <li class="c8"></li>
    <li class="c9"></li>
    <li class="c10"></li>
    <li class="c11"></li>
    <li class="c12"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**And my associated jQuery:**

```
$('.c1').hover(function () {
    $(this).parents().find('.chip-preview').css("background-position","-195px 0");
});
$('.c2').hover(function () {
    $(this).parents().find('.chip-preview').css("background-position","-390px 0");
});
$('.c3').hover(function () {
    $(this).parents().find('.chip-preview').css("background-position","-585px 0");
});
$('.c4').hover(function () {
    $(this).parents().find('.chip-preview').css("background-position","-780px 0");
});
$('.c5').hover(function () {
    $(this).parents().find('.chip-preview').css("background-position","-975px 0");
});
$('.c6').hover(function () {
    $(this).parents().find('.chip-preview').css("background-position","-1170px 0");
});
$('.c7').hover(function () {
    $(this).parents().find('.chip-preview').css("background-position","-1365px 0");
});
$('.c8').hover(function () {
    $(this).parents().find('.chip-preview').css("background-position","-1560px 0");
});
$('.c9').hover(function () {
    $(this).parents().find('.chip-preview').css("background-position","-1755px 0");
});
$('.c10').hover(function () {
    $(this).parents().find('.chip-preview').css("background-position","-1950px 0");
});
$('.c11').hover(function () {
    $(this).parents().find('.chip-preview').css("background-position","-2145px 0");
});
$('.c12').hover(function () {
    $(this).parents().find('.chip-preview').css("background-position","-2340px 0");
});
```

Each increment of class cN moves the background -195px on the horizontal. Ideas on how to make this better?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I've marked the one I'd like to use as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var xPosition = -195;
$(".style-swatches li").each(function(){
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $(this).parents().find('.chip-preview').css("background-position", (xPosition - ($(this).index() * 195)) + "px 0");
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zPtr6/3/)

Comment: You guys are quick! I've tried your example, but it only moves once and goes -2000px or so out. http://jsfiddle.net/zPtr6/

Comment: That was the old one.. i have modified my post please check with the modified code..

Comment: I saw you edited your code since I setup that jsfiddle. Your latest code works perfect! Excellent.. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.c1, .c2, .c3').hover(function () {
    var $this = $(this), pos = $this.attr('class').match(/\bc(\d+)\b/)[1];
    $(this).parents().find('.chip-preview').css('background-position','-' + (pos * 195) + 'px 0');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? (very crude, use carefully!)

```
$("[class^='c']").hover(function () {
    var classname = $(this).attr('class');
    var factor = substring(1);
    var position = Number(factor) * -195;
    position = position + "px 0";
    $(this).parents().find('.chip-preview').css("background-position", "-195px 0");
});
```